# Load Environment from systemd Config to a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, systemd

I want to import some environment Variables from the systemd Configuration Files `(*.conf)` of a service into a bash.

### Example

Under `/etc/systemd/system/test.service.d/*.conf` are some Config Files like ...

```
[Service]
Environment="VAR1=v1"
Environment="Var2=v2"
```

Depending on the alphabetical order of the files, they can override some values.
What I need are the values of the variables in my bash script.

Is there a direct command (from systemd) to import the variables in into a running bash script?
Does I have to parse the .conf files and import the variables manual?

Remark: The bash script is not started as systemd service.

Comment: Give a sample file an let you know what you need out of it.

Comment: Do you need to do this for all files or just for one specific instance?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any `systemd` command that would allow you to import such variables directly.

However, getting the variables to your script should not be a big problem (provided that you know in advance which variables you need and the syntax on the file). You could do something like the following:

```
MyVar1="$(grep -i 'Environment=\"VAR1=' /folder/file | cut -f3 -d'=' | cut -f1 -d'"')"
echo "$MyVar1"
v1
```

Some comments: note that `grep -i` makes the search case insensitive. Note the backslash escaping the quotes on `\"VAR1=`. Mind you, `cut -f3 -d'='` will divide the string in fields delimited by `=`, and it will delete everything before the third field -- in this case, it would delete everything before (and including) the second occurrence of `=`.

Answer (score 1):

Until now, I don't know a tool (from systemd) to read the variables into the bash.

A manual solution (with sed) to import the variables into the script can be:

```
source <( cat /etc/systemd/system/test.service.d/*.conf | 
  sed -rn 's/^Environment=("(.*)=(.*)")|((.*)=(.*))$/\2\5="\3\6"/p')
```

To have the variables available in the sub processes:

```
source <( cat /etc/systemd/system/test.service.d/*.conf | 
  sed -rn 's/^Environment=("(.*)=(.*)")|((.*)=(.*))$/export \2\5="\3\6"/p')
```